# AAPT: error: unknown element <uses-feature> found in debug Manifest

Tags: android, xml, react-native, android-manifest, aapt

I started using AAPT2 because for some reason my app keeps crashing on camera and I may have found the error from what this tells me:

```
android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:43: AAPT: error: unknown element <uses-feature> found.
android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:47: AAPT: error: unknown element <uses-permission> found.
android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:48: AAPT: error: unknown element <uses-permission> found.
```

And here is the debug manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.myapp.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="myapp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="myapp"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        **<!-- Problem Occurs Here -->**
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="true" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <activity
            android:name="cn.finalteam.rxgalleryfinal.ui.activity.MediaActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme_Light.Default" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme_Light.Default" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.imagepicker.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.dylanvann.fastimage.OkHttpProgressGlideModule"
            android:value="GlideModule" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have looked at other similar questions to mine and found that you have to remove said line or place it else where. But I am unfamiliar with placement of XML and I might cause even more problems. Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you!

Src Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="myapp"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  tools:replace="label"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="myapp"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: `<uses-feature>` elements belong outside of the `<application>` tags, as direct children of `<manifest>`. Same for `<uses-permission>` elements.

Comment: @MikeM. it places it back inside the application for some reason when I go to build again.

Comment: You're editing the wrong file then. You want to edit the one under `src/`, not `build/` or `debug/` or whatever it is.

Comment: I updated my question, I don't have the `uses-feature` element in the src manifest @MikeM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />` outside of `<application>` tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    ...

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.myapp.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="myapp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I go to use `react-native run-android` it places it back inside the `application`. Is there a reason why that is?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams You might be editing incorrect file. change the file under `src/../AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: In my src manifest I don't have the `<uses-feature>` tag. I also added my src manifest in the question above.

Comment: Yes, I just put the `uses-feature` in the src manifest and also it outside the application in the debug manifest. Still the same result. Is there a way I can maybe exclude it from the debug while building? Or what could be causing it to appear there?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams Clean (delete the debug folder if necessary) and don't change the manifest file in debug folder. Try to rebuild again

Comment: Ok I have good and bad news. So when I placed the `uses-feature` in the src manifest it does correctly appear outside the application. But a duplicate one appears inside the application. Maybe it has something to do with the package I am using here: https://github.com/mg365/react-native-customized-image-picker

Comment: I fixed the error. Thank you! Though I am still crashing when I try to open the camera.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams great! Enjoy coding